# Changing UserDataFolder in TWebBrowser with Edge engine

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser, delphi-11-alexandria, edgeengine

When using [TEdgeBrowser](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.Edge.TEdgeBrowser) directly it is possible to set custom [UserDataFolder](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.Edge.TCustomEdgeBrowser.UserDataFolder) property value. Is there a way to set it when using [TWebBrowser](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser) with Edge [engine](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser.SelectedEngine)?

Edit: found workaround: set [`WEBVIEW2_USER_DATA_FOLDER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/webview2-idl?view=webview2-1.0.1054.31#code-try-2) environment variable before creating component:

> When creating a WebView2Environment the following environment variables are verified:
>
> ```
> WEBVIEW2_BROWSER_EXECUTABLE_FOLDER
> WEBVIEW2_USER_DATA_FOLDER
> WEBVIEW2_ADDITIONAL_BROWSER_ARGUMENTS
> WEBVIEW2_RELEASE_CHANNEL_PREFERENCE
> ```

Comment: You may also [answer your own question instead of editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with Delphi 11.2 there is now [TWeBrowser.EdgeUserDataFolder](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser.EdgeUserDataFolder) property